# When Using Devise with Hyperloop is Hyperloop::Application.acting_user_id accessible from Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperstack

Following https://github.com/barriehadfield/hyperloop_devise_tutorial
when you call Hyperloop::Application.acting_user_id from rails console you get:

NoMethodError: undefined method `client_drivers_get_acting_user_id' for Hyperloop::ClientDrivers:Class

Is this expected behaviour or a should define some extra helper method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial was written when the project was called `Hyperloop` but it has been renamed `Hyperstack` so the tutorial is out of date.

We are in the process of removing all the Hyperloop references.

Try using `Hyperstack::Application.acting_user_id` and it should work. As I see it implemented here: https://github.com/hyperstack-org/hyperstack/blob/5a9dfac633a27a9b271d69650fabde28737bd0aa/ruby/hyper-operation/lib/hyper-operation/transport/client_drivers.rb#L17

The tutorial needs updating - sorry about that!

Comment: So is it just missing from hyperloop (i am on 0.9.6). Will a patch or backport work?

Comment: Is there any chance than controller is not defined for console and that is causing the whole error?